# How to reflect a point around a line in hexagonal coordinates

Tags: reflection, hexagonal-tiles

I have a hexagonal coordinate system as shown here:

[image: The hexagonal coordinate system I use.]

(If you'd like a better understanding of the coordinate system, I learned it from [here](http://keekerdc.com/2011/03/hexagon-grids-coordinate-systems-and-distance-calculations/))

I would like to reflect points (hexagons) across given lines. In fact, the only lines I need to reflect across are those defined by the border of `(0, 0)` and the other hexagons around it.

For example, the border of `(0, 0)` and `(1, 0)` creates a line. `(0, 1)` and `(1, -1)` would both be points on this line. The hexagon bordering `(0, 0)` that helps define the line (in this case, `(1, 0)`), I'll call the "bordering hexagon".

My question is this: Is there an easier algorithm than the one I describe below that takes the coordinates of the bordering hexagon and another hexagon on the grid (called the objective hexagon), and returns the coordinates of the objective hexagon after a reflection over the line defined by `(0, 0)` and the bordering hexagon?

My current method is:

1. Use the coordinates of the bordering hexagon as a vector perpendicular
   to the reflection line
2. Take the coordinates of the two bordering hexagons surrounding our original bordering hexagon, and subtract them `(x2-x1, y2-y1)` to get a vector parallel to the reflection line
3. Use a change of coordinates matrix to convert the coordinates of the objective hexagon into parallel and perpendicular components such that `(perpendicular component)*(perpendicular vector)+(parallel component)*(parallel vector) = (objective hexagon coordinates)`
4. The result of the reflection is then `(objective hexagon coordinates)+2*(perpendicular component)*(perpendicular vector)`

Does anyone know of a better way? This seems fairly complicated for such a seemingly simple problem.